# Is SS7 attack traceable/detectable?

Tags: mobile, social-media, ss7

There is a lot of talk about [SS7 attacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDJ-88e_06A). Even if old [article](http://www.cyberdefensemagazine.com/ss7-flaw-allows-hackers-to-spy-on-every-conversation/), but still interesting.

But lets say, someone accessed my account which uses two-step authentication (SMS verification method) and I started to suspect the SS7 attack like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDJ-88e_06A). I want to report it to the mobile network provider, but I do not know if this is even traceable? Could they identify and confirm this?